# Map/Flatten Nested Attributes in Both Directions

Tags: java, mapstruct

I have an entity class like:

```
class SomeEntity {
  int id;
  string name;
  date created;
}
```

and I have a dto class like:

```
class SomeDto {
   class SomeDtoAttributes {
      string name;
      date created;
   }

   string id;
   SomeDtoAttributes attributes;
}
```

Basically all properties on the Entity except for the id get put inside an attributes property on the dto.

I would like this mapper to be reusable for other entities/dtos that will follow the same pattern, but will have different properties.

I've read the documentation, but I am not clear on how to achieve this. Currently I have something like:

```
abstract class EntityMapper<DTO, DTOA E> {

    abstract E toEntity(DTO dto, DTOA attributes);

    abstract DTO toDto(E entity);

    abstract DTOA toDtoAttributes(E entity);

    abstract List<E> toEntityList(List<DTO> dtos);

    abstract List<DTO> toDtoList(List<E> entities);

    @AfterMapping
    protected void afterMapping(@MappingTarget DTO dto, E entity) {
        DTOA dtoAttributes = this.toDtoAttributes(entity);
        dto.setAttributes(dtoAttributes);
    }
}
```

But i don't like how I have to pass in both the `dto` and `dtoAttributes` in the `toEntity` method, and the `toEntityList` method doesn't populate the attribute properties on the returned entities.

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: Is every DTO class going to contain an inner DTOAttribute class that reflects the matching entity? If so, why not just have a DTO constructor that takes the entity and maps the non-id fields to a new DTOAtribute class instance? If not, can you use java reflection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all your entities and dtos look like this. You can achieve something like this with the help of some interfaces and generics.

```
class SomeDto implements Dto<SomeDtoAttribute> {
   class SomeDtoAttributes implements DtoAttributes {
      String name;
      date created;
   }

   String id;
   SomeDtoAttributes attributes;
}
```

Then in your mapper you can do

```
abstract class EntityMapper<DTO extends Dto<DTOA>, DTOA, E> {

    E toEntity(DTO dto) {
        E entity = toEntity(dto.getAttributes());
        if (entity != null) {
            entity.setId(dto.getId());
        }
        return entity;
    }

    @Mapping(target = "id", ignore = true)    
    abstract E toEntity(DTOA dtoAttributes);

    abstract DTO toDto(E entity);

    abstract DTOA toDtoAttributes(E entity);

    abstract List<E> toEntityList(List<DTO> dtos);

    abstract List<DTO> toDtoList(List<E> entities);

    @AfterMapping
    protected void afterMapping(@MappingTarget DTO dto, E entity) {
        DTOA dtoAttributes = this.toDtoAttributes(entity);
        dto.setAttributes(dtoAttributes);
    }
}
```